# Activity when push notification is clicked (Android)

Tags: android, notifications, backendless

I am using push notifications from backendless and I can recieve the notification but when I receive push notification and I click on it in the app bar it automatically redirects me to the main activity.

I want it to redirect to the open another activity when I click on the push notification.

I searched for the problem and found that I have to add the following lines in the Android Mainfest file in the activity that I want to open.

```
<activity android:name=".ShowMessage">

<intent-filter>

<action android:name="com.example.user.notificationfromc.MESSAGE"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>
```

(com.example.user.notificationfromc.) is my package name

(ShowMessage) is the activity that I want to open.

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
yourNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
```

Comment: where should I place this code? in the main activity or in the activity that I want to open once the  notification is clicked? I'm sorry but I'm new to android development. Also, the (yourNotification) variable what should I replace it with ?